# SSL certificate dates

Tags: date, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm configuring an Apache server for SSL, and in particular have generated a fresh CA key and certificate file. Here's the command I used to create the certificate:

```
>openssl req -config openssl.cnf -key private/CA.key -new -x509 -days 7300 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -out certs/CA.pem
```

When I check the dates in the CA.pem file, here's what I see:

```
>openssl x509 -dates -noout -in certs/CA.pem
notBefore=Feb 16 04:48:07 2018 GMT
notAfter=Jan  5 22:19:51 1902 GMT
```

Does this look right? I would have expected notAfter to be a later date than notBefore, and I have no idea why notAfter is set to a date in 1902.

Thanks for any help, Martin

Comment: If you are running an **_old_** version of OpenSSL (0.9.x) on a 32-bit system, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly the problem. I installed openssl 1.0.21 and the problem was resolved.